# How to determine hadronic relative partial decay widths?

Tags: particle-physics, symmetry, quarks, mesons, hadron-dynamics

For example in [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/037026939500579A) paper ([also on arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9505219)), the author writes:

> However, for an $n \bar n$ state, $\gamma^2(K \bar K) = \frac{1}{3} \gamma^2(\pi \pi)$, ...

Where $n \bar n = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} (u\bar u + d\bar d)$ and $\gamma$ is the partial width of the decay.

Is this a straightforward calculation I don't see or does it require heavy theory?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 1):

This result follows from assuming perfect [$SU(3)_{flavour}$ symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_Way_(physics)#SU(3)) and the [OZI rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OZI_rule).  The theory is not very heavy but there are multiple steps.

We start with $SU(3)_{flavour}$ symmetry, i.e the assumption that the strong interaction is indifferent to the [flavour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_Way_(physics)) of light $u$, $d$, and $s$ quarks. This symmetry is actually broken by the different masses and charges of the quarks, but it is usually not a bad approximation. (This is why the [eightfold way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_Way_(physics)) worked so well in explaining meson states observed in the 1960s and which led to the development of the [quark model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_model).)

Following the "ideally mixed" Equation 11 of Curtis Meyer's lecture on [Light and Exotic Mesons](http://www.curtismeyer.com/material/lecture.pdf),  we start by writing the $n \bar n$ state as
$$n \bar n =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (u\bar u + d\bar d) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}f_8 + \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}f_1 $$
in terms of the two [isoscalar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoscalar) $SU(3)_{flavour}$ states

$$f_8=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\left(u\bar u + d \bar d - 2 s \bar s\right) \textrm{ and }
f_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left(u\bar u + d \bar d + s \bar s\right)$$

The decay amplitudes into pions and kaons are
$$\gamma(n \bar n \rightarrow \pi\pi) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}\gamma (f_8\rightarrow \pi\pi) + \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\gamma(f_1 \rightarrow \pi\pi)
= \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}} C_{f_8\rightarrow \pi\pi} g_T + \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}C_{f_1\rightarrow \pi\pi})g_1$$
$$\gamma(n \bar n \rightarrow K\bar{K})
= \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}} C_{f_8\rightarrow K\bar{K}} g_T + \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}C_{f_1\rightarrow K\bar{K}}g_1$$
where $g_T$ and $g_1$ are coupling constants and the $C$ are  [$SU(3)$ Clebsch–Gordan coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients_for_SU(3)) determined by the [hypercharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercharge) $Y$ and [isospin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isospin) $I$ of the initial and final states.

Since [kaons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaon) and [pions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion) are members of an $SU(3)$ octet and the $n \bar n$ state has $(Y,I)=(0,0)$, for $n \bar n$ decays into $\pi\pi$ or $K\bar{K}$ we must look at the $(Y,I)=(0,0)$ listings of $\mathbf{8}\bigoplus\mathbf{8}$ Clebsch–Gordan coefficients in a source such as [Table 8.4 of Unitary Symmetry and Elementary Particles](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Yck3BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA141#v=onepage&q&f=false) by D. B. Lichtenberg (or we could just look at the bottom of page 9 of Meyer). Since pions, kaons, and anti-kaons have $(Y,I)=(0,1)$, $(1,\frac{1}{2})$ and $(-1,\frac{1}{2})$, we find that
$$C_{f_8\rightarrow \pi\pi} = -\frac{\sqrt{15}}{5} = -\sqrt{\frac{12}{20}}
 \textrm{ and } C_{f_1\rightarrow \pi\pi} = \frac{\sqrt{6}}{4} = \sqrt{\frac{3}{8}}$$
$$C_{f_8\rightarrow K\bar{K}} = \frac{\sqrt{10}}{10} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{20}} \textrm{ and } C_{f_1\rightarrow K\bar{K}} = \frac{1}{2} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{8}}$$
$$C_{f_8\rightarrow \bar K K} = -\frac{\sqrt{10}}{10} = -\sqrt{\frac{2}{20}} \textrm{ and } C_{f_1\rightarrow \bar K K} = -\frac{1}{2} = -\sqrt{\frac{2}{8}}$$
(Note that all $\pi\pi$ states are included in the $(I_1,Y_1;I_2,Y_2) = (1,0;1,0)$ row in the Clebsch-Gordan table, but $K\bar K$ and $\bar K K$ are in different $(\frac{1}{2},1; \frac{1}{2},-1)$ and $(\frac{1}{2},-1; \frac{1}{2},1)$ rows, so we must calculate them separately. This is not obvious from Meyer's derivation, where the $K\bar{K}$ amplitudes at the bottom of page 12 are a factor of 2 inconsistent with the $K\bar{K}$ rates shown in his Fig. 4.)

Inserting these values for the coefficients in the $n \bar n$ decay amplitudes we have:
$$\gamma(n \bar n \rightarrow \pi\pi)
= -\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}} \sqrt{\frac{12}{20}} g_T + \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\sqrt{\frac{3}{8}}g_1
= -\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}} g_T + \frac{1}{2}g_1$$
$$\gamma(n \bar n \rightarrow K\bar{K})
= \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}} \sqrt{\frac{2}{20}} g_T + \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}\frac{1}{2}g_1
= \sqrt{\frac{1}{30}} g_T + \sqrt{\frac{1}{6}}g_1$$
$$\gamma(n \bar n \rightarrow \bar K K)
= -\sqrt{\frac{1}{30}} g_T - \sqrt{\frac{1}{6}}g_1$$
(The first two of these are just Meyer's Eqs. 21 & 22 for ideal mixing angle.)

In order to figure out the relation between $g_T$ and $g_1$, we consider the amplitude for the decay of the
$$s\bar{s} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}f_8 - \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}f_1 $$
state into pions, i.e.
$$\gamma(s\bar{s}\rightarrow \pi\pi)
= \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} C_{f_8\rightarrow \pi\pi} g_T - \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}C_{f_1\rightarrow \pi\pi}g_1
=-\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}} g_T - \sqrt{\frac{1}{8}}g_1.$$
This decay can only happen if the $s\bar{s}$ quarks annihilate each other, which is suppressed according to the [OZI rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OZI_rule). The rate is zero under the assumption of perfect OZI suppression, in which case
$$\sqrt{\frac{2}{5}} g_T = -\sqrt{\frac{1}{8}}g_1
\qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad g_1=-\sqrt{\frac{16}{5}} g_T$$

From this we can calculate the $ n\bar n$ decay rates:
$$\gamma^2(n \bar n \rightarrow \pi\pi)
= \left(-\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}} g_T - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{16}{5}} g_T\right)^2
= \frac{9}{5} g_T^2$$
$$\gamma^2(n \bar n \rightarrow K\bar{K})
= \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{30}} g_T - \sqrt{\frac{1}{6}}\sqrt{\frac{16}{5}} g_T\right)^2
= \frac{9}{30} g_T^2$$
$$\gamma^2(n \bar n \rightarrow \bar K K )
= \frac{9}{30} g_T^2$$

Finally, the ratio of $n \bar{n}$ decays into two pions or kaons is
$$\frac{\gamma^2(n \bar n \rightarrow \pi\pi)}{\gamma^2(n \bar n \rightarrow K \bar{K} )+\gamma^2(n \bar n \rightarrow \bar K K )}
= \frac{\frac{9}{5} g_T^2}{2\frac{9}{30} g_T^2}=3$$
i.e. the value stated by [Amsler and Close](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9505219).